# How to style header in react-navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to style the header in `react-navigation` where the object is automatically generated by Expo.

I am trying to style the header background and the orientation of the title.

I tried every possible place, including `navigationOptions` but all failed.

In below code tab bar background color is correctly changed. But same method failed for header.

Any guidance appreciated.

```
import React from 'react';

import { createStackNavigator, createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

import LinksScreen from '../screens/LinksScreen';
import SettingsScreen from '../screens/SettingsScreen';

const LinksStack = createStackNavigator({
    Links: LinksScreen,
});

LinksStack.navigationOptions = {
    tabBarLabel: "Links",
    tabBarIcon: ...
};

const SettingsStack = createStackNavigator({
    Settings: SettingsScreen,
});

SettingsStack.navigationOptions = {
    tabBarLabel: "Settings",
    tabBarIcon: ...,
};

export default createBottomTabNavigator(
    {
        LinksStack,
        SettingsStack,
    },
    {
        tabBarOptions: {
            style: {
                backgroundColor: '#123456',
            },
        }
    },
);
```

Comment: what version of react navigation are you using?

Comment: ^2.18.2 is the value in package.json

Comment: Thats a pretty old version, I'd recommend upgrading if you can. The latest version is 5. However the docs are here for header customization in version 2 maybe it can help https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/2.x/headers.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```js
static navigationOptions = {
  title: 'Chat',
  headerStyle: { backgroundColor: 'red' },
  headerTitleStyle: { color: 'green' },
}
```

Comment: In the code that Expo generated, there is no `static navigationOptions` but there is `LinksStack.navigationOptions`. And when that object is added `headerStyle`, it does not work. That was also tried before I sent the question.

Comment: try reloading your app once.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
  export default createBottomTabNavigator(
  {

    LinksStack: {
      screen: LinksStack,
      navigationOptions: LinksStack.navigationOptions(), // style here
    },
    SettingsStack,
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this by passing using headerStyle inside each screen by

`export default createBottomTabNavigator({
  LinkStack: {
    screen: LinkScreen,
    navigationOptions: { // you need to call LinkStack.navigationOptions here
      headerTitle: 'LinkScreen',
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: 'red',
        ...otherStyles,
      }, 
    },
  }
})`

Or you can make use of `defaultNavigationOptions` inside your stackNavigator if you don't have specific header styles for your different screens.

In your case, you need to call `LinkStack.navigationOptions` for navigationOptions.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I figured out what I was doing wrong.

It seems I was searching the answer in wrong place. The following change solved the problem:

```
class LinksScreen extends React.Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        title: "Links Title",
        headerStyle: { backgroundColor: '#123456', },
        headerTitleStyle: { color: "#654321" },
    };
...
}
```